# I need to get division result and reminder in a tableau calculated filed

Tags: tableau-api

I have a below case statement need to be done correcting.

```
CASE [HourMinuteCompletedtime_res]
WHEN 0 THEN [HourMinuteCompletedTime_rem]
ELSE '+'[HourMinuteCompletedtime_res][HourMinuteCompletedTime_rem]
END
```

Should be as

```
CASE [HourMinuteCompletedtime_res]
WHEN 0 THEN [HourMinuteCompletedTime_rem]
ELSE '(+[HourMinuteCompletedtime_res])'[HourMinuteCompletedTime_rem]
```

Comment: Can anyone correct above case statement

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly answer your question, in the future please tell us what the fields are (including their data type) and what your expected result is.

Assuming res and rem are integers, and you want your output to be: `(+res) rem`

Use:

`CASE [HourMinuteCompletedtime_res]
  WHEN 0 THEN STR([HourMinuteCompletedTime_rem])
  ELSE "(+" + STR([HourMinuteCompletedtime_res]) + ") " + STR([HourMinuteCompletedTime_rem])
END`